# binance api getting makerCommission, two sources two different results

Tags: python, binance-api-client

Has anyone an idea what to make of the difference of makerCommission. Once I call it from client.account and the other time I user get_trade_fee().

get_account()

```
>>> print(json.dumps(client.get_account(), indent=2))
{
  "makerCommission": 10,
  "takerCommission": 10,
```

get_trade_fee()

```
>>> client.get_trade_fee(symbol="XRPBUSD")
[{'symbol': 'XRPBUSD', 'makerCommission': '0', 'takerCommission': '0.001'}]
```